# Scrolling voting button stays in front of answer when scrolled sideways

Tags: bug, user-interface

This may already have been raised, but I couldn't find it when I searched.

If the voting button is in scrolling mode, it floats in front of the text if you scroll horizontally.  Obviously not a huge problem on most browsers since you don't need to scroll horizontally, but it makes it quite hard to read when zoomed in on a mobile phone...

You can simulate by making your browser window smaller. See the *2* in the screen shot below.

[image: Scrolled voting button]

Comment: Did you consider not zooming? It is breaking everything! ;) I was able to reproduce this as well.

Comment: Closing this because the sticky vote controls feature [has been removed again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please). Thanks for the report though.

Answer (score 8):

They are doing this by using `position:fixed;top:20px;` here for the "vote cell". The upshot is that it doesn't use js to determine the offset and as a result there is no extra processing or flickering. The downside is that even as you scroll to the right it is still fixed in the same place on the screen.

A simple fix from an outside point of view would be to make the voting cell go behind the answer text. A small problem with this is that the answer background is transparent and has no indexing on it. So the solution to this would be two fold (assuming that this is viable with other aspects of design which would need tests to approve)

Add a directive to the element which already has position fixed either in css or in style assignment from javascript which is how I think it is currently done.

```
.js-vote-sticky.is_stuck
{
    z-index: 0;
}
```

And then for the answer space, add in a position:relative to allow the z-index:1 to apply and give a non transparent (white) background.

```
td.answercell /*this definition already exists*/
{
    vertical-align: top; /*this definition already exists*/
    z-index: 1; /*new addition*/
    position: relative; /*new addition*/
    background-color: white; /*new addition*/
}
```

Here is an example of it scrolling to be behind the answer

[image]